# Case Statement for Exists subquery with Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following query that I need to add an additional column to indicate whether a grouping of rows contains a specific value ('PROB) (in one or more rows) within a column; If the grouping does contain this value then output 'Y', Else output 'N'. I added a `CASE` statement that you will see notated below with comments.

I am getting the error `Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.`

I'm unsure how I can fix this because I need to be able to test if this value exists in this column, based on the `Group By`.

```
SELECT A.HRS_PERSON_ID, A.HRS_RCMNT_ID , A.HRS_OFF_ID , A.POSITION_NBR , (CONVERT(CHAR(10) ,A.OFFER_DT ,121)) , (CONVERT(CHAR(10) ,A.HRS_PROP_ST_DT ,121)) ,
(CONVERT(CHAR(10) ,A.HRS_OFR_DT_EXP ,121)) , A.HRS_ONLN_OFR_POSTD , A.JOBCODE , A.HRS_HIRING_MGR_ID , A.RECRUITER_ID , A.WC_COUNCIL_ID , B.OFFER_AMT ,
B.CURRENCY_CD , B.OFFER_FREQUENCY , B.ERNCD , B.EARNS_AMT , B.LOCATION , C.OFFER_COMPONENT , (CONVERT(CHAR(10) ,C.EFFDT ,121)) , C.DESCR , C.DESCRSHORT ,
C.OFFER_TYPE , C.MONETARY_IND , D.APP_PER_STATUS , D.EMPLID , D.HRS_EXT_TRN , D.POI_TYPE , F.COUNTRY_NM_FORMAT , F.NAME , F.NAME_INITIALS , F.NAME_PREFIX ,
F.NAME_SUFFIX , F.NAME_ROYAL_PREFIX , F.NAME_TITLE , F.LAST_NAME , F.FIRST_NAME , F.MIDDLE_NAME , F.NAME_DISPLAY , F.NAME_FORMAL , E.ADDRESS_TYPE , E.COUNTRY ,
E.ADDRESS1 , E.ADDRESS2 , E.ADDRESS3 , E.ADDRESS4 , E.CITY , E.NUM1 , E.NUM2 , E.HOUSE_TYPE , E.COUNTY , E.STATE , E.POSTAL , G.DESCR , B.SEQUENCE_NUMBER ,
H.HRS_DESCR , J.HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID , I.DESCR , I.ADDRESS1 , I.CITY , I.STATE , I.POSTAL , M.DESCR , N.DESCR , M.SAL_ADMIN_PLAN, M.STEP_FROM,
(CONVERT(CHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10),121)), M.SEC_CLEARANCE_TYPE, 

---BELOW IS MY CASE STATEMENT I CREATED:
CASE WHEN EXISTS (  SELECT OFFER_COMPONENT 
                    FROM PS_HRS_OFF_CMPNT_I
                    WHERE OFFER_COMPONENT = C.OFFER_COMPONENT
                    AND OFFER_COMPONENT = B.OFFER_COMPONENT
                    AND OFFER_COMPONENT = 'PROB'  
                    GROUP BY A.HRS_PERSON_ID )
                    THEN 'Y'
                    ELSE 'N' 
                    END AS 'PROB_CODE'   
---END OF MY CASE STATEMENT---

FROM 
PS_HRS_OFFER_I A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PERSONAL_PHONE P ON P.EMPLID = A.RECRUITER_ID AND P.PHONE_TYPE = 'BUSN' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_HRS_HIRE Q ON A.HRS_PERSON_ID = Q.HRS_PERSON_ID AND A.HRS_RCMNT_ID = Q.HRS_RCMNT_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_GH_ENRLMNT_TBL R ON R.EMPLID = Q.EMPLID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_GH_SESSION_TBL S ON R.GH_SESSION_ID = S.GH_SESSION_ID 
, PS_HRS_OFF_DTL_I B, PS_HRS_OFF_CMPNT_I C, PS_HRS_APPLICANT D, PS_HRS_APP_NAME_I F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_HRS_APP_ADDR_I E ON F.HRS_PERSON_ID = E.HRS_PERSON_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_STATE_TBL G ON G.STATE = E.STATE AND G.COUNTRY = E.COUNTRY
, PS_HRS_PAYMODE_VW H, PS_LOCATION_TBL I, PS_HRS_RCMNT J, PS_HRS_JOB_OPENING K, PS_HRS_JO_RQMT L, PS_POSITION_DATA M, PS_DEPT_TBL N, PS_EMPLOYEES O 

WHERE 
C.OFFER_COMPONENT = B.OFFER_COMPONENT 
AND A.HRS_PERSON_ID = B.HRS_PERSON_ID 
AND A.HRS_RCMNT_ID = B.HRS_RCMNT_ID 
AND A.HRS_OFF_ID = B.HRS_OFF_ID 
AND A.HRS_PERSON_ID = D.HRS_PERSON_ID 
AND A.HRS_PERSON_ID = F.HRS_PERSON_ID 
AND C.OFFER_COMPONENT = H.OFFER_COMPONENT     
AND I.LOCATION = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
AND A.HRS_PERSON_ID = J.HRS_PERSON_ID 
AND A.HRS_RCMNT_ID = J.HRS_RCMNT_ID 
AND K.HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID = J.HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID 
AND K.HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID = L.HRS_JOB_OPENING_ID 
AND M.POSITION_NBR = A.POSITION_NBR     
AND O.EMPLID = A.RECRUITER_ID       
AND A.HRS_PERSON_ID = 91998
AND A.HRS_RCMNT_ID = 305223
```

**EDIT:** Here is a simplified example of the (desired) output (with fewer columns):
If the same HRS_PERSON_ID has at least 1 row with 'PROB' then make **all** rows for that person 'Y'. If a HRS_PERSON_ID does not have any rows with 'PROB' then make all rows 'N'

[image]

Comment: You should retrieve information from PS_HRS_OFF_CMPNT_I using left join and not sub query then test the retrieved values. Then construct a simple case instruction with the condition CASE OFFER_COMPONENT is null then ... else ...

Also, proper link your table with inner join when needed.

Comment: But how can I test for these values by `A.HRS_PERSON_ID` ? A HRS_PERSON_ID contains multiple rows for the same ID, and I need to know within an ID if the value 'PROB' exists. In the additional column I'm adding I want to set to 'Y' for all rows if 'PROB' exists on any of them, and set to 'N' on all rows if 'PROB' does not exist on any of them.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Plus, you're mixing old, comma separated joins with explicit joins. To join 19 tables. Plus `A.HRS_PERSON_ID = 91998`, so that's a constant anyway. Maybe have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's impossible to answer without the data structure.

Comment: The sub query for the EXISTS is only grouping by something outside that subquery. As such it isn't really being filtered to only look at the Person ID you're filtering to. Does the table PS_HRS_OFF_CMPNT_I include an identifier for the person? If so group by that and add a where clause to require that it equals the equivalent field in the outer query

Comment: I've add an sample of the desired output, hope this helps illustrates better.

Comment: The table PS_HRS_OFF_CMPNT_I does NOT have an identifier for the HRS_PERSON_ID unfortunately.

Comment: Change `CASE WHEN EXISTS (  SELECT OFFER_COMPONENT` to `CASE WHEN EXISTS (  SELECT 1` should solve your problem, but you will not learn why .... 

Comment: I tried changing the Subquery to Select 1.... but I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was easier than I was making it out to be, and did not require a `Group By`:

```
CASE WHEN        (SELECT top 1 OFFER_COMPONENT 
                  FROM PS_HRS_OFF_DTL_I
                  WHERE HRS_RCMNT_ID = B.HRS_RCMNT_ID                                    
                  AND HRS_OFF_ID = B.HRS_OFF_ID
                  AND OFFER_COMPONENT = 'PROB' )
                  IS NOT NULL
                  THEN 'Y'
                  ELSE 'N' END AS [PROB_CODE]
```

Answer (score -1):

Explanation of my comment:

If this query:

```
select i,j
from test
```

returns this

```
i           j
----------- -----------
1           10
2           10
3           10
4           9
```

Then, for some reason, you can do this query in MySQL

```
SELECT j
FROM test
GROUP BY i
```

But this query fails in MSSQL (as it should!) because MSSQL is not able to tell which value should be returned for `j`. Should it be the lower, the highers, or some random value (like what MySQL is doing).

The solution is to write something like:

```
SELECT MIN(j)
FROM test
GROUP BY i
```

to get the minimal value for j within each group.

Or, if you are really `clueless`, you can write:

```
SELECT 1
FROM test
GROUP BY i
```

This will return the value `1` for each group it finds.

Comment: This answer is not really useful in the context of what I am doing.